# Modals don't show up if I change Theme

Tags: spring, primefaces, modal-dialog

I have a Java project with Spring framework and primefaces. At the beginning I had some issues using the Themes of primefaces, because the suggested solutions did not work (I did not recieve an error message, the theme did not show up).

The suggested solution is to add the following lines:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>Prime Repo</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
```

to pom.xml and:

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>afterdark</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to web.xml. I also tried to manually download the .jar files for the themes and add them to the classpath, but this also did not work. The I found the following link:
[Combine hardcoded PrimeFaces resources using CombinedResourceHandler](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/wiki/Combine-hardcoded-PrimeFaces-resources-using-CombinedResourceHandler) which solved my problem and I was now able to add themes to my UI. However, since i added those lines to my code, the modal dialogs don't show up anymore. I don't get an error or something else, the don't pop up as usual.
This are the code snippets in the solution:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.application.ResourceDependencies;
import javax.faces.application.ResourceDependency;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.render.Renderer;

@ResourceDependencies({
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces-aristo", name="theme.css"),
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces", name="primefaces.js"), // Only necessary when at least one validation JS files needs to be included.
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces", name="validation/validation.js"), // Only necessary when you need <p:clientValidator>.
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces", name="validation/beanvalidation.js") // Only necessary when you use JSR303 bean validation.
})
public class HeadRenderer extends Renderer {

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        context.getResponseWriter().startElement("head", component);
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeChildren(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        // NOOP.
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        for (UIComponent resource : context.getViewRoot().getComponentResources(context, "head")) {
            resource.encodeAll(context);
        }

        context.getResponseWriter().endElement("head");
    }

}
```

and the following in the faces-config.xml:

```
<render-kit>
<renderer>
    <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
    <renderer-type>javax.faces.Head</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>com.example.HeadRenderer</renderer-class>
</renderer>
```